# Android: Cannot find element id/name in google form android

Tags: android, google-docs, google-forms, inspect

I am trying to integrate google form with android using this [link](http://www.androidmads.info/2016/10/google-form-to-android-application.html)

But when I created a google form as mentioned in the tutorial I was not able to find the name or id of the element by clicking inspect on the field.[image: Image Screenshot]

I am new to google form integration. Please help me how can I get the id or name of the element in the new google form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep attention that You want to send the data to a google form, **not to edit a google form from application but you are trying to find the name in edit form page** so, Create the google form first by :

Open it's link from upper right corner by pressing SEND button.

After that right click on an input you want to find it's name to use with your POST request.

### Instruction with picture :

**1st :**

[image]

**2nd :**

[image]

**3rd(Now you can find your desired form and it's inputs):**

[image]

Comment: after i send it I am back to the main form.what do i do now?

Comment: @ParthaChakraborty Just please wait a few seconds I will add instruction picture by picture for you.

Comment: @ParthaChakraborty Please check it.

Comment: can u tell me how do i test it whether I have posted it correctly?

Comment: @ParthaChakraborty You can see submitted data in form admin page.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not admin of the google form, then you will not find Prefill Link.

for that case inspect element - name/id is not present.

To get element name:

1. need to inspect the **Network Tab** of your Google form.
   [image]
2. first submit your Google Form and check for **formResponse**.
   [image]
3. in **formResponse** select **Payload**.
4. in Payload you will see many entries like **entry.130355623**